# QLabel margin and style sheet padding in labels in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a label, and I set both padding in the style sheet and a margin using `setMargin()`.

```
ui->label->setPixmap(redRectWithGreenBorder(80, 40));
ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel {border: 1px solid gray;border-radius: 2px;background-color: white;padding: 0px 5px 10px 15px;}");
ui->label->setMargin(5);
```

But this is how it looks in reality:

[image]

The visible margins are 5, 10, 15 and 20 (I checked with an image editor). That is, they are equal to the value of the style sheet for this side plus the value of `margin()`, i.e. 0+5, 5+5, 10+5, 20+5.

However, the documentation says this about `setMargin()`:

> margin : int This property holds the width of the margin.
>
> The margin is the distance between the innermost pixel of the frame
>   and the outermost pixel of contents.
>
> The default margin is 0.

If I were taking the documentation at face value, I would have expected the margin to be the real distance between the content and the border. But it is not. Instead, **the sum of the margin and the style sheet padding** is the real margin.

My question is, where in the documentation is this behavior described? Is there some other place in the documentation where this behavior is specified that I have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stylesheet padding applies to *all* controls, even those that are not based on `QLabel`. It exists in addition to any control-specific mechanisms. The `margin` is a `QLabel`-specific property that predates stylesheets; it was available in Qt 4.0 (at least). The stylesheets came later, in Qt 4.2.

Another way to think about it: The behavior can be inferred from the fact that there's only one `margin` property, not four. This property has nothing to do with stylesheet padding, since the latter give you 4 separate values of padding. There's no way to reconcile those other than adding them up.

Also, note that the `margin` and `padding` are different terms. The stylesheet specifies the padding. The `QLabel` specifies a margin. They may be synonyms, but that's irrelevant here. They are still different concepts within the setting of `QLabel`. The visual outcome is due to both. The 4.0 margin's behavior had to be preserved in Qt 4.2, so as not to break existing code.

Comment: OK, I'll accept the answer, but I'd like to point out that the docs say "The margin is the distance between the innermost pixel of the frame and the outermost pixel of contents." They don't say "unless there is style sheet padding". Note they define it as distance between outermost pixel and innermost pixel, so by that definition the documentation is simply not true.

Comment: @sashoalm In a `QLabel`, there is no single distance between the contents and the frame. The sentence you cite from the documentation is thus nonsensical on its face. It's a documentation bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QPushButton instead of QLabel. The QPushButton has not this bug. 
You can use advanced selectors to filter your replaced "QLabels".

use `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents` to make it not-clickable and use styleSheet to add them QLabel-like style.

I also have the problem and a bug is reported but not solved.

In QPushButton also there is bug. border:1px solid #000000; used in two stylesheets adds padding-left 1px... This technology is underdeveloped.